# Fail to get the php zeromq extension work

Tags: php, zeromq

I have follow the following to install the zeromq with php bindings, but when I try to run my code, I get the following error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/zmq.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/zmq.so: undefined symbol:
>   zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

Sites to follow for the installation of zeromq
http://zeromq.org/bindings:php

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: instead of step `phpize && ./configure` try `phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config`. You cannot fix this by php.ini or so, you need the correct versions of PHP and the module and get it compiled with the symbols in it somehow. Also should open a case here: https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the advice, I 've tried using phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config and then make install again, but with no luck. I have already specified the zmq.so in php.ini (both php cli and apache directory), but still no luck...

Comment: Sorry it did not work. The problem is not that the so file does not get loaded, the problem is that the C code of the module requires a symbol (like `#define zend_new_interned_string <value>`) which it cannot find. This can only be fixed while compilation or in the module source code. Your best bet is to open a case at zmq or contact them via email